# Transfer HashMap Data From Mobile to Android Wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Currently I am trying to develop an Android mobile/wear application, and I have encountered a problem where I need to send data contained in a Hashmap from the mobile device to the wear device. I looked at the Android developer guide, and it seems that I have to use a DataMap, but I am still lost as to how to store the HashMap data in a DataMap and properly retrieve the info on the wear device.

If someone could create an example of this process, or point me to examples of how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what types do you have in your `HashMap`, but assuming you have `HashMap<String, String>` you just need to go through all values and add copy them to `DataMap`.

```
public static DataMap toDataMap(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) {
    DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        dataMap.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return dataMap;
}
```

and later to create `HashMap` from `DataMap`

```
public static HashMap<String, String> fromDataMap(DataMap dataMap) {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String key : dataMap.keySet()) {
        hashMap.put(key, dataMap.getString(key));
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

Of course remember not to store anything else in such generated `DataMap` because you may override one of existing keys. So if you want to send anything else you should nest this `DataMap` inside another by using [putDataMap (String key, DataMap value)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataMap.html#putDataMap(java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap)) method on another `DataMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about DataMap as a trimmed down Bundle in which the primitive types (and a bit more than that) are supported; a HashMap can contain any type of objects and that is not something that DatMap supports, hence there is no api to map one to the other. You can traverse your HasMap and use DataMap.put**() methods to build a DataMap for the supported data types; if you have an object that DataMap doesn't support, you would need to serialize that one way or the other (say, build a json representation of your object) and then put that in the DataMap. Outside of that, there is nothing magical; build a DataMap based on what I described and then sync that across devices and get a DataMap on the other ends and reverse the process to populate a HashMap from the DataMap.